# Cast empty parameter to void

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have definition for Result type:

```
type ResultSuccess<T> = T extends void ? { isSuccess: true } : { isSuccess: true, value: T };
type ResultFailure = { isSuccess: false, error: string }
type Result<T> = ResultSuccess<T> | ResultFailure
```

Now I'm trying to have ResultCreator class that would be some kind of factory of Result for easier usage:

```
export class ResultCreator {
  static success<T>(value?: T): Result<T> {
    return { isSuccess: true, value: value } as Result<T> 
  }

  static failure<T>(errorValue: string): Result<T> {
    return { isSuccess: false, error: errorValue }
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that success method doesn't support empty (`void`) `value` and I'm not sure how can I achieve that. Perfect scenario would be that I can use it like this:

```
const emptyResult = ResultCreator.success();
if (emptyResult.isSuccess) {
  emptyResult.value // this doesn't exist, but currently it's unknown
}

const result = ResultCreator.success('my value');
if (result.isSuccess) {
  result.value // this is fine, value is string
}

const errorResult = ResultCreator.failure('failure');
if (errorResult.isSuccess == false) {
  errorResult.error // this works but what's funny is that it doesn't work if check is (!errorResult.isSuccess) 
}
```

Comment: Btw, nice avatar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it work, you need to overload your static method.
Also, no need to use type assertion `as Result<T>` because TS has structural type system

```js
type ResultSuccess<T> = T extends void ? { isSuccess: true } : { isSuccess: true, value: T };
type ResultFailure = { isSuccess: false, error: string }
type Result<T> = ResultSuccess<T> | ResultFailure


export class ResultCreator {
  // OVERLOADING
  static success(): { isSuccess: true }
  static success<T>(value: T): { isSuccess: true, value: T }
  static success<T>(value?: T) {
    return value ? { isSuccess: true, value: value } : { isSuccess: true }
  }

  static failure<T>(errorValue: string): Result<T> {
    return { isSuccess: false, error: errorValue }
  }
}


const emptyResult = ResultCreator.success();
if (emptyResult.isSuccess) {
  emptyResult.value // expected error
}

const result = ResultCreator.success('my value');
if (result.isSuccess) {
  result.value // this is fine, value is string
}

const errorResult = ResultCreator.failure('failure');
if (errorResult.isSuccess === false) {
  errorResult.error // this works 
}

if (!errorResult.isSuccess) {
  errorResult.error // this works
}
```

As for `!errorResult.isSuccess` as you might have noticed it works. Not sure why it did not work on your machine.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsAyogxph8A8AKgHxQC8UBUEAHsBAHYAm8UAbgPYCWjUA-FAG8oneBmy4AXFGAAnRNAC%20UKUJFic8eFNnyANGwCGyeVMoKA3AFgAUKEiwEKYADEDnYzOjlVorBq1QAGZG8BD6EDIy7DJS8LKc9ADmUAo2dtBwSKiEJOSZTuq4OVAAPg5ZLm4eEDa11jRg0cBQmMgGmuVOAMKeBsDRgjZQUHF9nJgjfrgAFACUKsK%204pracopDI8BjE0jL%20MTTrEYmFPOCi4Ur0mv6R8YQpikbo8Djk3s5h8cQvKazg9ZhsNPMBEDJ6IZ7nxzmoplcdGFISc7vIUsoYUt-KtUalAU9rM8tq8JsF3GCIJ8IlEZAA1b6xeJJM75bLEAFAqAgsEQnyXALBZChcKRaJSKnROlQ3HDXG4uqYdj0OJUAC2YFALOaeUcqB6ED60QAdLt-HMrNZOIEoNMIGqNTrgIbYXt-gINrb1SBNYaUdAAPR%20qjUSCYOg8cUyGxy6wKpXNTwVMidXW9foyY1w%20DTADkKpASIg2dm5st1oTTidmNwro25dQPu%20UAD0gAFiJFkEEojfR24jIEoko-LFcqI5qk5q9Qb06TqjnZ%20SiyWrTaRTJvc7-GRSOQBaEa3ixw7DRGm4HgG2WAB3aIAaxYQ4JFpXAEIjxVK3yD8N3xXT82L3bG8ZHvKMgA)

Answer (score 1):

For the omitted parameter to work, you'll have to set an overload. To prevent TypeScript's mysterious behavior when having to check `if (errorResult.isSuccess == false)`, use a type guard.

```js
type ResultSuccess<T> = T extends void
  ? { isSuccess: true }
  : { isSuccess: true; value: T };
type ResultFailure = { isSuccess: false; error: string };
type Result<T> = ResultSuccess<T> | ResultFailure;

function isSuccessful<T>(result: Result<T>): result is ResultSuccess<T> {
  return result.isSuccess;
}

export class ResultCreator {
  static success(): Result<void>;
  static success<T>(value: T): Result<T>;
  static success<T>(value?: T): Result<T> {
    return { isSuccess: true, value } as Result<T>;
  }

  static failure<T>(errorValue: string): Result<T> {
    return { isSuccess: false, error: errorValue };
  }
}

const emptyResult = ResultCreator.success();
if (isSuccessful(emptyResult)) {
  emptyResult.value; // error as expected
}

const result = ResultCreator.success('my value');
if (isSuccessful(result)) {
  result.value; // string
}

const errorResult = ResultCreator.failure('failure');
if (!isSuccessful(errorResult)) {
  errorResult.error; // string, errorResult is ResultFailure
}
```

I wonder why TS yells at me when I return `{ isSuccess: true, value }` without type assertion in `ResultCreator.success()`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I had to accept the other answer because it was the first one and solutions are pretty much the same.